# derivative of limit function vs limit of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Suppose that we have a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n$ converges to some function $f$. Then it is not necessary that the sequence of derivatives $f_n'$ converges. For example, if
$$f_n(x):=\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$
then $f_n$ converges (uniformly) to constant function $0$ but $f_n'$ diverges almost everywhere.

But what if we assume that the sequence $f_n'$ does converge for all $x$ and that $f$ is differentiable. Is it then the case that $f_n'$ converges to $f'$ for (almost) all $x$? If not, are there any other reasonable conditions (like uniform convergence) that we can add to make this work?

Comment: What kind of convergence do you have in mind?  Pointwise?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should had mentioned that.

Comment: You need to assume that the derivatives converge uniformly - see https://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/limit%20of%20derivatives.pdf.